# Is there a way to globally set a scale factor for sprites in Cocos2d V2 project?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have an iPad application which has a set of image assets with the -ipadhd suffix for retina display iPads. I know I can change the suffix for non-retina iPads in the AppDelegate of my project, so that it uses the HD graphics. 
But is there a way to set a 'global' scale factor rather than scaling each sprite to a factor of 0.5? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the code for the class CCFileUtils in the cocos2d library and override some of the methods their to return a globally set content scale whenever an image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look and am not sure where to start in there; when I get a chance, I'll have a proper look.